# calling apex method which does callout returns undefined in LWC while showing the correct result in apex debug logs

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, callout, asynchronous, promises

I have the following lwc code:

```
import findLocalityApex from '@salesforce/apex/NACController.findLocalityApex'
...
findLocality() {
        console.log('this.lat findLocality' + this.lat);
        console.log('this.lng findLocality' + this.lng);
        findLocalityApex({lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng})
        .then(data => {
            console.log('Locality');
            console.log(data);
            if(data.locality.numberLocality != null) {
                this.localityNumberFromCallout= data.locality.number;
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
            console.log(' error ', this.error);
        });
      }
...
```

where `findLocalityApex` is the backend apex method in `NACController` class which calls the `ResponseNACCallout` class which does the the callout.

The `NACController` class:

```
...
@AuraEnabled
public static ResponseNAC findLocalityApex(String lat, String lng) {
    ResponseNAC respNac = ResponseNACCallout.responseNacCallout(lat, lng);

    return respNac;
}
...
```

In the `ResponseNACCallout` which does the callout I instantiate `ResponseNAC respNAC = new ResponseNAC();` and after mapping the callout response with the `respNAC`, I simply return `respNAC` to the calling class which is the `NACController` class's `findLocalityApex` method, which does a return to the LWC.

The `ResponseNAC` class:

```
public with sharing class ResponseNAC {

    public Locality locality = new Locality();
    public NACError nacError;

    public class Locality {
        public Integer numberLocality;
        public String romanNumeralLocality;
        public Integer IdLocality;
    }

    public class NACError {
        private String message;

        public NACError(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I check the debug logs it returns the correct result, but in the lwc it is always undefined. The order seems to be as follows:

1. `this.lat findLocality`
2. `this.lng findLocality`
3. then goes back to where it was called where it console logs other
   stuff
4. And then enters the `.then` of `findLocalityApex` method and console logs the string Locality and an empty object and then goes into `.catch` where it throws the `error`.

Its out of order because it is asynchronous. But why I am not able to capture the result in the lwc?

Comment: What does the findLocalityApex method return?

Comment: an apex class that is used for mapping with the callout results

Comment: No, we need to see what the return value is. Obviously, it's an Apex class, but that doesn't describe the structure of the class.

Comment: Does it correctly include AuraEnabled annotations, for example?

Comment: @PhilW yes it is

Comment: should it be respNac instead of data in the lwc .then?

Comment: What you show is not annotated. Please show the full definition of the response classes.

Comment: @PhilW I made the changes.

Comment: None of the response attributes have @AuraEnabled annotations and without these the properties are not going to appear in the payload sent to the client.

Comment: @PhilW You are right. I did not know I had to annotate member variables also. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the @AuraEnabled annotation on attributes the attributes are not included in the JSON response. To remedy this, update your response class thus:

```
public with sharing class ResponseNAC {
    @AuraEnabled
    public Locality locality = new Locality();

    @AuraEnabled
    public NACError nacError;

    public class Locality {
        @AuraEnabled
        public Integer numberLocality;

        @AuraEnabled
        public String romanNumeralLocality;

        @AuraEnabled
        public Integer IdLocality;
    }

    public class NACError {
        @AuraEnabled
        public String message;

        public NACError(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware that public attributes don't always work with LWCs and you may need tonuse a public property (with getter and setter) instead.